# Am I doing something wrong with this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have a little discussion with my friends about my "resolution" and calculation of
$$\int_{-\infty}^1 e^{4x} \, dx.$$
I did 
$$\int_{-\infty}^1 e^{4x} \, dx =\int_{-1}^{\infty} e^{-4x} \, dx = \lim_{b\rightarrow \infty}\frac{-e^{-4b}}{4} + \frac{e^4}{4} = \frac{e^4}{4}.$$
What's my error on this calculation? Or i'm doing right?  Thanks for your points of views friends!

P.D.: My friends tell me that I'm using in a wrong way Barrow's rule.

Comment: What makes you think there is an error? You could have gone slightly more directly, integrating from $-b$ to $1$.

Comment: They say that I'm using in a wrong way Barrow's rule.

Comment: I find what you did perfectly correct, and based on solid geometric intuition. For the reader, it does have the disadvantage of skipping a step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution "rule" may not have been proved for improper integrals. But you applied it correctly, doing two steps in one. The minus sign was omitted, but the limits were interchanged to compensate. The calculation is correct. It would have been preferable to use a new dummy variable symbol, letting $x=-t$.

More directly, we can calculate
$$\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{-b}^1 e^{4x}\,dx.$$
An antiderivative is $\frac{1}{4}e^{4x}$, so we want
$$\lim_{b\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4}e^{4}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-4b}\right).$$